# How can I make a backup of a whole directory of a web site?

Tags: backup, html

There is a guide here http://lj.163.com/guide/ that I would like to back up. All the links that go to http://lj.163.com/guide/* I also need to back up, and on a few of those pages there is pagination that links to still more pages under the same directory. How can I backup this page and all of it's sub pages?

Comment: You can use the HTTrack Website Copier: http://httrack.com/ (no affiliation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the HTTrack Website Copier at http://httrack.com/. This is a free tool that you can install on your Windows PC (WinHTTrack; Windows 2000 and higher), OS X or Linux (WebHTTrack), and Android 2.2 and higher. You can use this tool to download entire websites or subdirectories and browse them offline. However, it does not crawl files that are orphans (i. e. files that are not directly or indirectly linked from the main directory) because it uses HTTP and crawls using links.

> **DISCLAIMER:** I have ABSOLUTELY NO AFFILIATION with the people who maintain the software. It's just a tool that I know and love that I am recommending here.